# How to auto wrap function call in try / catch?

Tags: python

I have a lot of getter functions like this:

```
get_property_a(default=None):
  try:
     self.data.get("field_1")[0].get("a")
  except Exception as e:
     return default

get_property_b(default=None):
  try:
     self.data.get("field_2")[0].get("b")
  except Exception as e:
     return default

...
```

Is there a way to not wrapping all the getters in try/except? It would be nice if it is some kind of annotation like this:

```
@silent_exec(default=None)
def get_property_b():
  self.data.get("field_2")[0].get("b")
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you `return` data in `try` statement? Right?

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?  Plus, what @vishes_shell said :)

Comment: This post may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572288/general-decorator-to-wrap-try-except-in-python

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *can* do this by writing your own decorator:

```
import functools

def silent_exec(default=None):
    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs):
            except Exception:
                return default
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

With that said, I'd be *very* wary of using this.  You should *very rarely* be catching *all* exceptions (as we've done here).  Normally you it's better to specify a tuple of exceptions that you actually expect and know how to handle...

```
import functools

def silent_exec(exceptions, default=None):
    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs):
            except exceptions:
                return default
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@silent_exec((IndexError, KeyError), default=None)
def get_property_b():
  self.data.get("field_2")[0].get("b")
```

This way, you don't end up catching/silencing *programming* errors -- those will still get raised, you can look at them in the logs or wherever they get reported and you can go back in and fix them.