# How to write a contextmanager to throw and catch errors

Tags: python, pytorch, contextmanager

I want to catch the runtime error `CUDA out of memory` on multiple occasions in my code. I do this to then rerun the whole training workflow with lower batch size. What is the best way to do that?

I am currently doing this:

```
try:
    result = model(input)
# if the GPU runs out of memory, start the experiment again with a smaller batch size
except RuntimeError as e:
    if str(e).startswith('CUDA out of memory.') and batch_size > 10:
        raise CudaOutOfMemory(e)
    else:
        raise e
```

I then catch the error `CudaOutOfMemory` outside my main function.

However, this is a pretty long piece of code that I need to repeat many times. Is there any way to make a context manager for this?

such that instead I can run:

```
with catch_cuda_out_of_mem_error:
  result = model(input)
```

Edit:
I want to create a context manager instead of a function because the functions I want to wrap the "try, except" around are not always the same. In my workflow, I have many functions that use a lot of GPU memory and I would like to catch this error in any of them.

Answer (score 1):

Using a context manager is about properly acquiring and releasing a resource. Here you don't really have any resource that you are acquiring and releasing, so I don't think a context manager is appropriate. How about just using a function?

```
def try_compute_model(input):
    try:
        return model(input)
    # if the GPU runs out of memory, start the experiment again with a smaller batch size
    except RuntimeError as e:
        if str(e).startswith('CUDA out of memory.') and batch_size > 10:
            raise CudaOutOfMemory(e)
        else:
            raise e
```

Then use it like

```
result = try_compute_model(input)
```

Comment: The Python developers are not so strict. E.g. the `contexlib.suppress` manager does not acquire/release resources.

Comment: Hi @mCoding thanks for your response! I want to create a contextmanager instead of a function because the function I want to wrap the "try, except" around is not always the same. In my workflow I have many functions that use a lot of GPU memory and I would like to catch this error in any of them. Sorry if my question was misleading in that sense

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by this post: [General decorator to wrap try except in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572288/general-decorator-to-wrap-try-except-in-python) I found an answer to my problem:

```
import torch
from contextlib import contextmanager


class CudaOutOfMemory(Exception):
    pass


@contextmanager
def catching_cuda_out_of_memory():
    """
    Context that throws CudaOutOfMemory error if GPU is out of memory.
    """
    try:
        yield
    except RuntimeError as e:
        if str(e).startswith('CUDA out of memory.'):
            raise CudaOutOfMemory(e)
        else:
            raise e


def oom():
    x = torch.randn(100, 10000, device=1)
    for _ in range(100):
        l = torch.nn.Linear(10000, 10000)
        l.to(1)
        x = l(x)


try:
    with catching_cuda_out_of_memory():
        oom()
except CudaOutOfMemory:
    print('GOTCHA!')
```